# CSS Aligning 2 Float Left and 1 Float Right

Tags: html, css

I have 3 div, 2 are floating left and the other floating right. However it is not aligning in the way I want.

```
.numb1, .numb2 {
   float: left;
   width: 60%;
   display: inline-block;
 }

.numb3, .numb4 {
   float: right;
  width: 35%;
  display: inline-block;
 }
```

Here is a snippet so you have an idea of what problem; https://jsfiddle.net/rnty32gt/

I want the class numb3 to be aligned with numb1. I tried to use inlineblock but it is not working. Sorry for my English.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**  preferably in a **Stack Snippet**. Although you have provided a link, if it was to become invalid, your question would be of no value to other future SO users with the same problem. See [**Something in my website doesn't work can I just paste a link**](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254428/something-in-my-web-site-or-project-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it).

Answer (score 1):

Make this way using this css and html

```css
.numb2 ,.numb3  {
    padding: 0;
    text-align: left;
    border: 1px solid #c4c4c4;
    margin: 5px 0;
    background: linear-gradient(180deg,#fff 0,#e6e6e6);
}

.numb1 {
 float: left;
    width: 60%;
}

.numb3 {
 float: right;
    width: 35%;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<h1>The float Property</h1>

<div class="numb1">
<div class="numb2">
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Phasellus imperdiet, nulla et dictum interdum, nisi lorem egestas odio, vitae scelerisque enim ligula venenatis dolor. Maecenas nisl est, ultrices nec congue eget, auctor vitae massa. Fusce luctus vestibulum augue ut aliquet. 
</div><div class="numb2">
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Phasellus imperdiet, nulla et dictum interdum, nisi lorem egestas odio, vitae scelerisque enim ligula venenatis dolor. Maecenas nisl est, ultrices nec congue eget, auctor vitae massa. Fusce luctus vestibulum augue ut aliquet. Mauris ante ligula, facilisis sed ornare eu, lobortis in odio. 
</div></div><div class="numb3">
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Phasellus imperdiet, nulla et dictum interdum, nisi lorem egestas odio, vitae scelerisque enim ligula venenatis dolor. Maecenas nisl est, ultrices nec congue eget, auctor vitae massa. Fusce luctus vestibulum augue ut aliquet. Mauris ante ligula, facilisis sed ornare eu, lobortis in odio. Praesent convallis urna a lacus interdum ut hendrerit risus congue. Nunc sagittis dictum nisi, sed ullamcorper ipsum dignissim ac. In at libero sed nunc venenatis imperdiet sed ornare turpis. Donec vitae dui eget tellus gravida venenatis. Integer fringilla congue eros non fermentum. Sed dapibus pulvinar nibh tempor porta. Cras ac leo purus. Mauris quis diam velit.
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is how you could do it to have it fixed as you wish. But you could also use flex-box. Here is some info about flex-box: https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_flexbox.asp

```css
div {
    padding: 0;
    text-align: left;
    border: 1px solid #c4c4c4;
    margin: 5px 0;
    background: linear-gradient(180deg,#fff 0,#e6e6e6);
}

.numb1, .numb2 {
 float: left;
    width: 60%;
}

.numb3 {
 float: right;
    width: 35%;
}
```

```html
<h1>The float Property</h1>

<div class="numb1">
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Phasellus imperdiet, nulla et dictum interdum, nisi lorem egestas odio, vitae scelerisque enim ligula venenatis dolor. Maecenas nisl est, ultrices nec congue eget, auctor vitae massa. Fusce luctus vestibulum augue ut aliquet. 
</div>

<div class="numb3">
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Phasellus imperdiet, nulla et dictum interdum, nisi lorem egestas odio, vitae scelerisque enim ligula venenatis dolor. Maecenas nisl est, ultrices nec congue eget, auctor vitae massa. Fusce luctus vestibulum augue ut aliquet. Mauris ante ligula, facilisis sed ornare eu, lobortis in odio. Praesent convallis urna a lacus interdum ut hendrerit risus congue. Nunc sagittis dictum nisi, sed ullamcorper ipsum dignissim ac. In at libero sed nunc venenatis imperdiet sed ornare turpis. Donec vitae dui eget tellus gravida venenatis. Integer fringilla congue eros non fermentum. Sed dapibus pulvinar nibh tempor porta. Cras ac leo purus. Mauris quis diam velit.
</div>

<div class="numb2">
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Phasellus imperdiet, nulla et dictum interdum, nisi lorem egestas odio, vitae scelerisque enim ligula venenatis dolor. Maecenas nisl est, ultrices nec congue eget, auctor vitae massa. Fusce luctus vestibulum augue ut aliquet. Mauris ante ligula, facilisis sed ornare eu, lobortis in odio. 
</div>
```

So as you can see i have changed the order of div2 and div3 in your HTML.

Answer (score 0):

There you go.

```css
div {
    padding: 0;
    text-align: left;
    border: 1px solid #c4c4c4;
    margin: 5px 0;
    background: linear-gradient(180deg,#fff 0,#e6e6e6);
}
.wrap-l
{
  margin:0px;
  float: left;
    width: 60%;
    border:none;
}
.numb1, .numb2 {
 
}

.numb3 {
 float: right;
    width: 35%;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrap-l">
<div class="numb1">
Text 1 
</div>

<div class="numb2">
Text 2 
</div>
</div>
<div class="numb3">
Text 3
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Doe,

If you want *div.numb3* align with *div.numb1* you should change the order like this:

```css
div {
    padding: 0;
    text-align: left;
    border: 1px solid #c4c4c4;
    margin: 5px 0;
    background: linear-gradient(180deg,#fff 0,#e6e6e6);
}

.numb1, .numb2 {
 float: left;
    width: 60%;
}

.numb3 {
 float: right;
    width: 35%;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<h1>The float Property</h1>

<div class="numb1">
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Phasellus imperdiet, nulla et dictum interdum, nisi lorem egestas odio, vitae scelerisque enim ligula venenatis dolor. Maecenas nisl est, ultrices nec congue eget, auctor vitae massa. Fusce luctus vestibulum augue ut aliquet. 
</div>

<div class="numb3">
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Phasellus imperdiet, nulla et dictum interdum, nisi lorem egestas odio, vitae scelerisque enim ligula venenatis dolor. Maecenas nisl est, ultrices nec congue eget, auctor vitae massa. Fusce luctus vestibulum augue ut aliquet. Mauris ante ligula, facilisis sed ornare eu, lobortis in odio. Praesent convallis urna a lacus interdum ut hendrerit risus congue. Nunc sagittis dictum nisi, sed ullamcorper ipsum dignissim ac. In at libero sed nunc venenatis imperdiet sed ornare turpis. Donec vitae dui eget tellus gravida venenatis. Integer fringilla congue eros non fermentum. Sed dapibus pulvinar nibh tempor porta. Cras ac leo purus. Mauris quis diam velit.
</div>

<div class="numb2">
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Phasellus imperdiet, nulla et dictum interdum, nisi lorem egestas odio, vitae scelerisque enim ligula venenatis dolor. Maecenas nisl est, ultrices nec congue eget, auctor vitae massa. Fusce luctus vestibulum augue ut aliquet. Mauris ante ligula, facilisis sed ornare eu, lobortis in odio. 
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: why I need to change? Is there a reason for that?

Comment: The reason is that the _float_ property will work for the contiguous element where you specified it

Answer (score 0):

give width: 30%; for numb1 and numb 2

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use floats, just put the .numb3 above the other divs in your markup : https://jsfiddle.net/5vbvjwcs/

Otherwise you can use flex :

```css
section {
  display: flex;
}

.leftColumn {
  width: 60%;
}

.content {
  padding: 10px;
  background-color: #eaeaea;
  margin: 10px;
  flex: 1;
}
```

```html
<section>
  <div class="leftColumn">
    <div class="content">
      Numb1
    </div>
    <div class="content">
      Numb2
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="content">
    Numb3
  </div>
</section>
```